# How to merge similar custom hooks into one custom hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a situation where there were created 4 custom hooks all very similar to each other.
Those use similar queries and mutations. The scope of all 4 is to manage an API called `StudyConfiguration`. I need to make it merged in one custom hook and in an efficient way.

The 4 custom hooks are called

- useConfiguration,
- useSetConfiguration,
- useStudyConfigurationOverride,
- useUnSetConfiguration

I tried to emerge as follows and below it, you will see the 4 custom hooks along with details of their usage. The goal is to have all 4 in one in the right way.

This is the new custom hook I did by merging the 4 in one but I'm not convinced that could be the right way

```
import { gql, useMutation, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { useCallback } from 'react';

const GET = gql`
  query WEB_useConfiguration($name: String!, $scope: StudyConfigurationScope) {
    studyConfiguration(name: $name, filter: $scope) {
      name
      value
      configurationOverrideChain {
        value
        scope
      }
    }
  }
`;

const GET_OVERRIDE = gql`
  query WEB_useConfigurationOverride($name: String!, $scope: StudyConfigurationScope) {
    studyConfiguration(name: $name, filter: $scope) {
      configurationOverrideChain {
        value
        scope
      }
    }
  }
`;

const SET = gql`
  mutation WEB_setConfiguration($input: setStudyConfiguration!) {
    setStudyConfiguration(input: $input) {
      name
      value
    }
  }
`;

const UNSET = gql`
  mutation WEB_unSetConfiguration($input: unsetStudyConfiguration!) {
    unsetStudyConfiguration(input: $input) {
      name
      value
    }
  }
`;

const useConfiguration = ({ name, scope, defaultValue = null }) => {
  const { data } = useQuery(GET, {
    variables: { name, scope },
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  });

  const value = data?.studyConfiguration?.value;

  if (!value) {
    return defaultValue;
  }

  try {
    return JSON.parse(value);
  } catch {
    return value;
  }
};

const useStudyConfigurationOverride = ({ name, scope }) => {
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_OVERRIDE, {
    variables: { name, scope },
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  });

  const value = data?.studyConfiguration?.configurationOverrideChain;

  if(!value) return []

  return value;
};

const useSetConfiguration = input => {
  const [setStudyConfiguration] = useMutation(SET);

  const executeSetConfiguration = useCallback(() => {
    return setStudyConfiguration({ variables: { input: { ...input } } });
  }, [input, setStudyConfiguration]);

  return [executeSetConfiguration];
};

const useUnSetConfiguration = input => {
  const [unSetStudyConfiguration] = useMutation(UNSET);

  const executeUnSetConfiguration = useCallback(() => {
    return unSetStudyConfiguration({ variables: { input: { ...input } } });
  }, [input, unSetStudyConfiguration]);

  return [executeUnSetConfiguration];
};

export { useConfiguration, useSetConfiguration, useUnSetConfiguration, useStudyConfigurationOverride };
```

Now the single hooks with an example of how they are used

**useConfiguration**

This custom hook is for getting the `Study configuration` from the API and returns a `value`. The reason we have a try/catch is that depending on what config is requested the value can be a string or a boolean. So if the parse fails we return the value directly.

```
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

const QUERY = gql`
  query WEB_useConfiguration($name: String!, $scope: StudyConfigurationScope) {
    studyConfiguration(name: $name, filter: $scope) {
      name
      value
    }
  }
`;

export const useConfiguration = ({ name, scope, defaultValue = null }) => {
  const { data } = useQuery(QUERY, {
    variables: { name, scope },
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  });

  const value = data?.studyConfiguration?.value;

  if (!value) {
    return defaultValue;
  }

  try {
    return JSON.parse(value);
  } catch {
    return value;
  }
};
```

The above is used as an example

```
const emailSender = useConfiguration({
    name: 'messaging.email.sender.address',
    scope: { studyId },
  });
```

In this case, we get back a string like `value = email@email.com`

**useStudyConfigurationOverride**

This custom hook is actually almost the same as the above one but we getting the second part of the result of the same query. It is giving back `configurationOverrideChain` which is an array of tracked changes for the configuration

```
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

const QUERY = gql`
  query WEB_useConfigurationOverride($name: String!, $scope: StudyConfigurationScope) {
    studyConfiguration(name: $name, filter: $scope) {
      name
      configurationOverrideChain {
        value
        scope
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const useStudyConfigurationOverride = ({ name, scope }) => {
  const { data } = useQuery(QUERY, {
    variables: { name, scope },
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  });

  const value = data?.studyConfiguration?.configurationOverrideChain;

  if(!value) return []

  return value;
};
```

An example of usage

```
const studyOverrides = useStudyConfigurationOverride({
    name: 'messaging.email.sender.address',
    scope: { studyId },
  });
```

results in an array of the overrides as

```
[
  {
    "value": "global@test.com",
    "scope": "GLOBAL"
  },
  {
    "value": "noreply@test.com",
    "scope": "STUDY"
  },
  {
    "value": "hello@app.trialbee.com",
    "scope": "DEFAULT"
  }
]
```

**useSetConfiguration**

This custom hooks set a new configuration

```
import { gql, useMutation } from '@apollo/client';
import { useCallback } from 'react';

const SET_STUDY_CONFIGURATION = gql`
  mutation WEB_setConfiguration($input: setStudyConfiguration!) {
    setStudyConfiguration(input: $input) {
      name
      value
    }
  }
`;

export const useSetConfiguration = input => {
  const [setStudyConfiguration] = useMutation(SET_STUDY_CONFIGURATION);

  const executeSetConfiguration = useCallback(() => {
    return setStudyConfiguration({ variables: { input: { ...input } } });
  }, [input, setStudyConfiguration]);

  return [executeSetConfiguration];
};
```

Example of usage

```
const [setNoReplyStudyEmail] = useSetConfiguration({
    name: 'messaging.email.sender.address',
    value: noReplyEmail,
    scope: { studyId },
  });
```

**useUnsetConfiguration**

This custom hook is for remove the configuration setted like from above mutation

```
import { gql, useMutation } from '@apollo/client';
import { useCallback } from 'react';

const UNSET_STUDY_CONFIGURATION = gql`
  mutation WEB_unSetConfiguration($input: unsetStudyConfiguration!) {
    unsetStudyConfiguration(input: $input) {
      name
      value
    }
  }
`;

export const useUnSetConfiguration = input => {
  const [unSetStudyConfiguration] = useMutation(UNSET_STUDY_CONFIGURATION);

  const executeUnSetConfiguration = useCallback(() => {
    return unSetStudyConfiguration({ variables: { input: { ...input } } });
  }, [input, unSetStudyConfiguration]);

  return [executeUnSetConfiguration];
};
```

Example

```
const [setSmsMessagingDefault] = useUnSetConfiguration({
    name: 'messaging.recruitment.sms.enable',
    scope: { studyId },
  });
```

As extra details this is a component using this implementation

```
import {
  useConfiguration,
  useSetConfiguration,
  useStudyConfigurationOverride,
  useUnSetConfiguration
} from '@lib/hooks/useConfiguration';
import { FormControlLabel, FormGroup, Switch, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useIntl } from 'react-intl';

const StudyConfiguration = ({ studyId }) => {
  const intl = useIntl();

  // !TODO: make one smart hook/s

  // Tracking the study scope/value
  const studyOverrides = useStudyConfigurationOverride({
    name: 'messaging.email.sender.address',
    scope: { studyId },
  });
  console.log('studyOverrides: ', studyOverrides);

  // Getting the study config
  const smsEnabled = useConfiguration({
    name: 'messaging.recruitment.sms.enable',
    scope: { studyId },
    defaultValue: false,
  });

  console.log('smsEnabled: ', smsEnabled);

  const emailSender = useConfiguration({
    name: 'messaging.email.sender.address',
    scope: { studyId },
  });

  console.log('emailSender: ', emailSender);

  const [studyConfOverride, setStudyConfOverride] = useState(studyOverrides);
  const [valueEmailReply, setValueEmailReply] = useState(emailSender);
  const [valueSmsConf, setValueSmsConf] = useState(smsEnabled);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (studyConfOverride.length !== studyOverrides.length) {
      setStudyConfOverride(studyOverrides);
    }
  }, [studyOverrides]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  useEffect(() => {
    if (valueEmailReply !== emailSender) {
      setValueEmailReply(emailSender);
    }
  }, [emailSender]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  useEffect(() => {
    if (valueSmsConf !== smsEnabled) {
      setValueSmsConf(smsEnabled);
    }
  }, [smsEnabled]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  // Building the default reply email based on 'SCOPE'
  // !TODO: study overrides sort in study service (TBD)
  let defaultEmail;
  if (studyOverrides.find(o => o.scope === 'GLOBAL')) {
    const { value } = studyOverrides.find(o => o.scope === 'GLOBAL');
    defaultEmail = value;
  } else if (studyOverrides.find(o => o.scope === 'DEFAULT')) {
    const { value } = studyOverrides.find(o => o.scope === 'DEFAULT');
    defaultEmail = value;
  }

  // Extracting the email domain from default email and used to make a 'noreply@domain.xxx'
  const emailDomain = defaultEmail?.substring(defaultEmail.indexOf('@'));
  const noReplyEmail = `noreply${emailDomain}`;

  // Set study config
  const [setNoReplyStudyEmail] = useSetConfiguration({
    name: 'messaging.email.sender.address',
    value: noReplyEmail,
    scope: { studyId },
  });

  const [setSmsMessagingDisable] = useSetConfiguration({
    name: 'messaging.recruitment.sms.enable',
    value: 'false',
    scope: { studyId },
  });

  // unSet study config
  const [setDefaultStudyEmail] = useUnSetConfiguration({
    name: 'messaging.email.sender.address',
    scope: { studyId },
  });

  const [setSmsMessagingDefault] = useUnSetConfiguration({
    name: 'messaging.recruitment.sms.enable',
    scope: { studyId },
  });

  const handleReplyEmailChange = async event => {
    setValueEmailReply(event.target.checked ? defaultEmail : noReplyEmail);
    event.target.checked
      ? await setDefaultStudyEmail()
      : await setNoReplyStudyEmail();
  };

  const handleSmsConf = async event => {
    setValueSmsConf(event.target.checked);
    event.target.checked
      ? await setSmsMessagingDefault()
      : await setSmsMessagingDisable();
  };

  const isEmailEnabled = valueEmailReply === defaultEmail;

  return (
    <FormGroup>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <Switch
            data-testid="email-reply"
            checked={isEmailEnabled}
            onChange={handleReplyEmailChange}
          />
        }
        label={
          <Typography color="textPrimary">
            {intl.formatMessage(
              {
                defaultMessage:
                  'Allow candidates to reply to emails (send from  {replyEmailTxt} instead of {noReplyTxt})',
              },
              { replyEmailTxt: defaultEmail, noReplyTxt: noReplyEmail },
            )}
          </Typography>
        }
      />
      <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <Switch
            data-testid="sms-enable"
            checked={valueSmsConf}
            onChange={handleSmsConf}
          />
        }
        label={
          <Typography color="textPrimary">
            {intl.formatMessage({
              defaultMessage: `SMS messaging`,
            })}
          </Typography>
        }
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
};

export default StudyConfiguration;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case of someone will have similar issues.
After hours I found the following solution merging all the custom hooks into one hook.

The solution

```
import { gql, useMutation, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { useCallback } from 'react';

const GET = gql`
  query WEB_useConfiguration($name: String!, $scope: StudyConfigurationScope) {
    studyConfiguration(name: $name, filter: $scope) {
      name
      value
      configurationOverrideChain {
        value
        scope
      }
    }
  }
`;

const SET = gql`
  mutation WEB_setConfiguration($input: setStudyConfiguration!) {
    setStudyConfiguration(input: $input) {
      name
      value
    }
  }
`;

const UNSET = gql`
  mutation WEB_unsetConfiguration($input: unsetStudyConfiguration!) {
    unsetStudyConfiguration(input: $input) {
      name
      value
    }
  }
`;

const useGetConfiguration = ({ name, scope, defaultValue }) => {
  const { data } = useQuery(GET, {
    variables: { name, scope },
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  });
  const value = data?.studyConfiguration?.value;
  const overrideChain = data?.studyConfiguration?.configurationOverrideChain;

  const studySettings = {};

  if (!value) studySettings.value = defaultValue;
  else {
    try {
      studySettings.value = JSON.parse(value);
    } catch {
      studySettings.value = value;
    }
  }
  if (!overrideChain) studySettings.overrideChain = [];
  else {
    studySettings.overrideChain = overrideChain;
  }
  return studySettings;
};

const useSetConfiguration = ({ name, scope }) => {
  const [setStudyConfiguration] = useMutation(SET);

  const executeSetConfiguration = useCallback(
    (value) =>
      setStudyConfiguration({ variables: { input: { name, scope, value } } }),
    [name, scope, setStudyConfiguration],
  );

  return executeSetConfiguration;
};

const useUnsetConfiguration = input => {
  const [unsetStudyConfiguration] = useMutation(UNSET);

  const executeUnsetConfiguration = useCallback(
    () => unsetStudyConfiguration({ variables: { input: { ...input } } }),
    [input, unsetStudyConfiguration],
  );

  return executeUnsetConfiguration;
};

export const useConfiguration = ({ name, scope, defaultValue = null }) => {
  // GET
  const studySettings = useGetConfiguration({ name, scope, defaultValue });

  // SET
  const setStudyConfiguration = useSetConfiguration({ name, scope });

  // UNSET
  const unsetStudyConfiguration = useUnsetConfiguration({ name, scope });

  return [studySettings, setStudyConfiguration, unsetStudyConfiguration];
};
```

and an example of how it is used in a possible component

```
const [emailSettings, setSenderEmail, unsetSenderEmail] = useConfiguration({
    name: 'messaging.email.sender.address',
    scope: { studyId },
  });
```